# SOAP: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: linux, soap

This is my receiver code:

```
import socket
import time

IP = '192.168.1.99'
PORT = 8084

DEBUG = False

# Printing is only enabled in debug mode
def print_(*args):
    if DEBUG:
        print(*args)

def get_ms():
    ms = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    return ms

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((IP, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    while 1:
      data = conn.recv(1024)
      if not data: break
      text, ts = data.decode('utf-8').split()
      delay = get_ms() - int(ts)
      response = 'ACK ' + str(text) + ' ' + str(delay) + ' ' + str(get_ms())
      # Simulate server processing delay
      time.sleep(0.008)
      conn.send(response.encode('utf-8'))

    conn.close()
```

After I run it I get an error:

```
ERROR: Cannot assign requested address
```

If I run the receiver and sender code on same RPI I don't get this problem, but when I try to connect with a different RPI i get the error.

Comment: Have you remembered to change the IP address to match the new machine?

Comment: Yes, the IP address is correct. Is it possible that I'm somehow blocking the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP address at the top of your program does not match the machine you are running the code on.

If you had included the full error from the failure:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 20, in <module>
    s.bind((IP, PORT))
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

We could see that the problem is on line 20 which is `s.bind((IP,PORT))`

In order to bind a server socket to a specific address you need to give an address that the machine has locally. If you want to bind to just the loopback address (so it can only be accessed from the same machine then you should use `127.0.0.1`. If you want the program to be accessible from all addresses then you should use `0.0.0.0`.